# What is the best way to store negatives from the 1940s and '50s?

Tags: film

These were stored in their canisters for over 60 years. I have copied all of them. What is the best way to store them? Should I straighten them out and put them in protective sleeves? Or should I leave them as-is, since they are getting brittle to straighten?

Comment: These were developed and stored back in the cassette? Interesting. I'd at least start with getting archive safe sheets and a archive binder. Maybe call\email the US National Archives for some advice...